# how can i host a website multiple times on nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express

```js
const { response } = require('express');
const express = require('express');
const { request } = require('http');
const app = express();
app.listen(3000, () => console.log ('listening at 3000'));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.json({limit: '1mb'}));
app.post('/api', (request, response) => {
    console.log('Incoming data:');
    console.log(request.body);
});
```

my code is here. my question in the title. how can i host public folder in the code more than one with different ports and ip's?

Comment: You could use something like `nginx` configured as a reverse proxy.

Comment: It's not very clear what are you trying to achieve. Do you want to reduce load from your server, or increase aviability somehow?

Comment: @AlexShtromberg i wanna to host the same site multiple times so i can classify users on local network.

Comment: @unknown oh, wow, very interesting! What does it mean "classify users on local network"?

Comment: @AlexShtromberg i will separate the incoming data according to which user comes from which port and process it to the database accordingly.

Comment: @unknown why is there a need for diffrent ports? Just identify the user based on whatever and process the data as needed.

Answer (score -1):

To my knowledge I do not believe it is possible to do this without creating lots of express servers which in my opinion is not best practice and may crash your server.

You may want to look at alternate solutions such as [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/). You could setup Nginx virtual hosts to host multiple files.

Comment: then can i host the site once and distribute it from different ports and find out which data is coming from which port?

Comment: Its unclear what you mean when you want to use different ports. Could you not use some sort of browser cookie system or session system instead of whole entire servers?

Comment: the methods you said dont fit the system i am trying to do, this is the only solution i could find.